# GetElementById() not finding the tag?

Tags: c#, xml, getelementbyid

I have a valid XML file being read by the following .NET C# windows service.
The tag in question (u1_000) is absolutely in the element:

```
<book id="u1_000" category="xyz">
```

Is there some reason the GetElementById() does not find the Book element with the tag? - thanks

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\j.xml");
XmlElement ee = doc.GetElementById("U1_000");

<book id="U1_000" category="web">
```

Comment: Can you post your XML document (or a sample)?  Are you establishing what the ID is in the doctype?

Comment: actually, no not in the doc type - I will look into that. Thought specifying the id was enuf ;( - thanks

Comment: Nope, there is nothing magic about the attribute name “id”. “xml:id”, on the other hand... http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/

Comment: Just a guess, but are element IDs case sensitive?

Comment: They are case sensitive. But this tag here I changed from the original to protect the innocent (and me). The original cases did match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If nothing else, perhaps use xpath as a backup:

```
string id = "u1_000";
string query = string.Format("//*[@id='{0}']", id); // or "//book[@id='{0}']"
XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode(query);
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I will go this route. Great idea. Thanks to Anthony as well.

Answer (score 4):

You need a DTD to establish which attribute on elements would consitute the unique id.  In XML it isn't automatically assumed that the `id` attribute should be treated as a unique element ID.

In general "unDTDed" XML the getElementById is not very useful.  It most cases the structure of the XML file being processed is understood (for example the root element is called `books` that contains a series of `book` elements) hence a typical access would look something like this:-

```
 XmlElement book = (XmlElement)doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("book[@ID='U1_000']");
```

If you really don't know the XML structure and/or the tag name of the element then the brute force search described in Marcs answer would work.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [MSDN documentation for this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx).  In the sample below you can see how they establish what the ID is using the DOCTYPE.  This may fix the problem for you.