# Why does XmlDocument.GetElementById always return null?

Tags: c#, xmldocument, sgmlreader

I've got some XML (valid XHTML) that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <![CDATA[
                function change_header(){
                    document.getElementById("myHeader").innerHTML="Nice day!";
                }]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="myHeader">Hello World!</h1>
        <button onclick="change_header()">Change text</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I'm trying to get the `#myHeader` node using `docment.GetElementById("myHeader")` but it always returns `null`. Why?

I'm *guessing* it doesn't recognize the `id` attribute as *the* id attribute without a DTD or something? If that's the case, how can I get it to use an HTML DTD?

Comment: Same as [
GetElementById() not finding the tag?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003185/getelementbyid-not-finding-the-tag).

Comment: Matthew, I don't think it's the same. This one works by just removing the CDATA in both firefox and chrome.

Comment: @Gonzalo: You've completely misinterpreted the question. Have a look at the tags. This has nothing to do with JavaScript. I'm trying to parse the HTML in C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because XmlDocument knows nothing about what an `id` means. You need to include a DTD in your XHTML document. Just put the following in the beginning of your html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Example:

```
string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd""><html><body><div id=""foo"">some content</div></body></html>";
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(html);
XmlElement div = document.GetElementById("foo");
```

Notice that this might be a little slower because the DTD needs to be downloaded.

Comment: The document is coming from the web in the form of a stream. Is there another way to set the doctype?

Comment: I am afraid you will need to load it into memory, append the correct DTD and then load it into an XmlDocument. Of course if you intend to parse HTML I would recommend you using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Using XmlDocument for parsing invalid web pages (ones without DTD for example) is a perilous task.

Comment: Trying `SgmlReader` instead. Wasn't too fond of HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer to close this thread, but I went to look for the "id" attribute instead because it's easier.