# XmlDocument.GetElementById() is returning null

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dtd

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE taxes[
<!ELEMENT tax (name,percent,description)>
<!ATTLIST tax id CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT percent (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
]>
<taxes>
    <tax id="Tax-1">
        <name>Tax 1</name>
        <percent>6.75</percent>
        <description>Ohio sales tax</description>
    </tax>
</taxes>
```

And my C# code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("path-to-file");

XmlElement element = doc.GetElementById("Tax-1");
```

Whenever I try to do stuff with `element`, I get a `NullReferenceException`.

I did some research and I found that a valid DTD is required, but as far as I know everything is valid...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3775800/815938

Comment: @kennyzx did you read the question? I already have a DTD and this is not HTML...

Comment: Based on http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/attlist_declaration.shtml & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx it seems like you have to declare id as ID in the DocType and not as CDATA.

Comment: Would you show us please your full error message. Is `element` null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DTD is incorrect.
For your XML proper DTD is:

```
<!DOCTYPE taxes[
<!ELEMENT taxes (tax*)>
<!ELEMENT tax (name,percent,description)>
<!ATTLIST tax id CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT percent (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
]>
```

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you so much. I also changed the CDATA for "id" to ID and that seems to work fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!ATTLIST tax id ID #REQUIRED>
```

Your id attribute on your tax element could also be called something other than id, e.g., taxid:

```
<!ATTLIST tax taxid ID #REQUIRED>
```